# Django: Show which form fields are required

Tags: django, forms, django-forms

Is there an easy enough way for `.as_table()` (et al.) of a form to show required fields differently (for example adding asterisk after the field label)?

Django 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set [`required_css_class`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.required_css_class) for the form:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):
    required_css_class = 'required'
```

This will add the `required` css class to the required fields’ labels (and the `tr` tags if you are using `{{ form.as_table }}`.

You can then use CSS to style the required fields/labels as you wish. You can use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::after) to append text (e.g. `*`) to the labels of required fields.